# ExpressJS not sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, typescript

I am working on a project where I need an angular web app to be able to access a node/express based backend, and I am attempting to use Cors. However, the express server seemingly won't send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and I have no clue why. I've tried creating a middleware as such:

```
this.app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
}
```

I've also tried doing something similar individually for each request, using setHeader(), header(), set() and append(), but none of these work either. I'm currently using the cors npm package, but that also isn't working with the following code:

```
this.app.use(cors({
        origin: "http://localhost/4200"
    }));
this.app.options("*", cors({
            origin: "http://localhost/4200"
        })
    );
```

I've checked that none of these are adding the relevant header to the response via postman. Express is adding the "error" header I use to give a human-readable description of the error, but not "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

I'm writing this in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you restart your express server after making the change?
- Did you try also adding the [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the express server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check your middleware is invoked on request?
2. Did you check your middleware is registered before `listen` is called?

If both is guaranteed it must have a reason depending on a other part of your Application. So you should provide more information about booting and structure of files and directories.

Comment: The middleware is added before listen is called.

Comment: Okay, looks like the middleware isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't with the code, but with the compiler setup. I deleted and recreated the tsconfig.json file, and it works now.